# How can I mount this drive in Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, remote-access

Here is the output from `df -h`:

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/mapper/rootvg-rootvol  39G   31G  5.7G  85% /  
/dev/sda1                   99M   13M   82M  14% /boot  
tmpfs                       2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm  
nasfs01d-ops-99.big.corp.com:/bigco/data  
                           257G  608K  257G   1% /mnt
```

And my `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/rootvg/rootvol     /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
LABEL=SWAP-sda2         swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

How can I mount and use the last drive (257G)?

Answer (score 1):

It is mounted, that's why it's appearing in your mount table (which df is showing you)!

The last field, 'Mounted on', tells you where in your file system it is. So you can access the files on the drive by looking at the contents of /mnt.

Comment: I tried accesing using 

     cd /mnt

and then tried creating a new file

     sudo mkdir newDir

yet I am getting a permssion denied error?

Comment: You probably don't have access to create files on the remote server as root, hence the error. Try it as a normal user instead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the drive is already mounted.  This is an NFS share, you can tell by the machine:/export/path syntax on the left (the device type).

If you want to know how to mount it now, it's already mounted.

If you want to know how to mount it by hand, as root, type:

```
mount -t nfs nasfs01d-ops-99.big.corp.com:/bigco/data /some/local/mount/point
```

If you want it mounted every time you rebooted, you'd need to change your /etc/fstab and add this line:

```
nasfs01d-ops-99.big.corp.com:/bigco/data /some/local/mount/point nfs default 0 0
```

I'd think a bit about putting it in /etc/fstab - this means you would then have a boot dependency on that NFS server, and it may hang your box on boot if the NFS is unavailable.  You could configure your box to mount it using the automounter, which would bring in the mount only when needed, but that's out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: Thanks I could at least unmount and remount again. It seems my sysadmin hasnt set proper permissions or something, coz I still cannot create a directory or touch a file.

Answer (score -1):

It is already mounted per your df -h output.  If you're getting a permission denied error when you cd /mnt, try:

```
chmod 777 /mnt
```

However, you may need to chmod from the nas server (nasfs01d-ops-99.big.corp.com):

```
chmod 777 /bigco/data
```

777 is just for troubleshooting, so be sure to use the appropriate permissions for security's sake.

Comment: 777 permissions are a bad idea. Even for troubleshooting..